# Remove MySQL row with button

Tags: php, mysql

I am really struggling here and not sure why. I am trying to remove a row in my data base when the user click the delete button thats in the same button as the row their trying to remove.

**Home.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive sortable">
                        <tr class="header">
                            <td>id</td>
                            <td>Rep</td>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>P_O</td>
                            <td>Due Date</td>
                            <td>Terms</td>
                            <td>Aging</td>
                            <td>Open Balance</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                                $className ="";
                                if ($row['Aging'] >= 45)
                                {
                                    $className="danger";
                                }
                                else if($row['Aging'] >= 25 && $row['Aging'] <= 44)
                                {
                                    $className="warning";
                                }

                                echo "<tr class='$className'>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Rep']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['P_O']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Due_Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Terms']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Aging']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Open_Balance']."</td>";
                                echo "<td><button id='" .$row['id']. "' value='" .$row['id']. "' class='btn btn-danger'> Delete</button></td>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

**deletepage.php**

```
    // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $userID = (int) $_GET['id'];
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
        $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM Book1 WHERE id='$userID'");
    }
    if($delete){
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Sorry, record could not be deleted";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `<button action='deletepage.php'` action typically meant to go on a `<form>` tag. Is the table wrapped in a form? If not, you'll want to start there, with `<form action="deletepage.php" method ="GET">`...

Comment: okay i have wrapped the mysql portion of my table in  FORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect with mysqli, use mysqli throughout.
I've added an i here:

```
        $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM Book1 WHERE id='$userID'");
```

And change your button once to this. You aren't passing the variable to get currently, you;d do that by adding a question mark to the URL and specifying variables. Also, Since you are using twitter bootstrap, anchors with class `btn` will look like a button, so a form is not necessary.

```
echo "<td><a href='deletepage.php?id=" .$row['id']. "' value='" .$row['id']. "' class='btn btn-danger'> Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: okay i change the line of code, however still when i click the delete button nothing happens.

Comment: were getting somewhere it gets me to the deletepage.php and gave me the error that is was unable to delete the row?

Comment: It is still giving me the Sorry, record could not be deleted error. Im updating the main post with the changes @Octopi

Comment: I added the `$conn` variable, did you use that?

Comment: When i click the delete button this is the url it shows when getting the error message deletepage.php?id=

Comment: It looks like you dont have a row id. Are you sure thats the correct name and not userid by any chance?

Comment: yeah there is no userID in my database table just "id"

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU ROCK!!!! Ive been at this for hours lol thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 2):

1. Starting at `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {`, it looks like you start a `<tr>`, but it doesn't look like you ever close it. At the bottom of your `<td>`s, you'll want a echo "";
   Not a huge deal, and this won't fix your issue.
2. Like I said in the comment, action isn't realyl an attribute of `<button>`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Browser_compatibility)

What you will probably need to do is wrap it in a form, which you said you did, and add `type="submit"` to the button tags.

```
<form action="deletepage.php" method="GET">
    ...table html
    echo "<td><button id='" .$row['id']. "' type="submit" value='" .$row['id']. "' class='btn btn-danger'> Delete</button></td>";
</form>
```

This sounds like what your issue is, to me at least. You need to submit an html form to deletepage.php, or try another route like an AJAX request to deletepage.php.